# I am doing "Read & Write Data from Excel File in Selenium Webdriver: POI & JXL"

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am doing "Read & Write Data from Excel File in Selenium Webdriver: POI & JXL"

```
package ExcelExportAndFileIO;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

public class ReadExcelFile {

    public void readExcel(String filePath, String fileName, String sheetName) throws IOException
    {
         //Create an object of File class to open xlsx file
        File F1 = new File(filePath +"\\"+ fileName);

        //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(F1);

        Workbook workbook = null;

        //Find the file extension by splitting file name in substring  and getting only extension name

        String fileExtenstionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));

         //Check condition if the file is xlsx file
        if(fileExtenstionName.equals(".xlsx"))
        {
            //If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
        }

        //Check condition if the file is xls file
        else if(fileExtenstionName.equals(".xls")){

            //If it is xls file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class

            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputstream);

        }

        // Read sheet inside the workbook by its name

         org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

        //Find number of rows in excel file

         int rowCount = worksheet.getLastRowNum() - worksheet.getFirstRowNum();

        //Create a loop over all the rows of excel file to read it

         for(int i=0; i<rowCount+1;i++)
         {
             Row row = worksheet.getRow(i);

            //Create a loop to print cell values in a row
             for(int j=0;j<worksheet.getLastRowNum();j++)
             {
                //Print Excel data in console
                 System.out.println(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"||");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }

    }

    //Main function is calling readExcel function to read data from excel file
    public static void main(String...strings) 
    {

        //Create an object of ReadExcelFile class
        ReadExcelFile ObjreadExcel = new ReadExcelFile();

        //Prepare the path of excel file
        //String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\ExcelExportAndFileIO";
        String filePath = System.getProperty("E://Jotsna//Other//Joey//SELENIUM//Workspace//DolphinRFID//src//ExcelExportAndFileIO");

        //Call read file method of the class to read data
        ObjreadExcel.readExcel(filePath, "ExportExcel.xlsx", "ExcelDemo");
    }
}
```

Error coming on console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>   at ExcelExportAndFileIO.ReadExcelFile.main(ReadExcelFile.java:73) 
>   Please Help. Thank you in advance.*

Comment: Which line is 73?

Comment: Issue got resolved. It was because of improper import statement.